# how to append associative arrays into another array inside loop - php

Tags: php, arrays

I really hope you help me with this problem, I hope this make sence for you
- I have this pseudo example of foreach loop:

```
foreach_loop {

$k1 = GetKey1(); 
$v1 = GetValue1();

$k2 = GetKey2();
$v2 = GetValue2();

$k3 = GetKey3();
$v2 = GetValue3();

//  now I put those keys and values in associative array called DataArr
 $DataArr[$k1] = $v1;
 $DataArr[$k2] = $v2;
 $DataArr[$k3] = $v3;

}
```

now my question is, how do I create an array where each index of it contain an associative array created from that `foreach` loop and keep appending to itself like this:

```
     $resultArr = array(
     0 => "DataArr_from_loop1",
     1 => "DataArr_from_loop2",
     2 => "DataArr_from_loop3",
     3 => "DataArr_from_loop4"
     //...etc
     )
```

and when I check for `$resultArr[0]` I should get an associative array like this:

```
    array (size=3)
    'k1' => string 'v1'
    'k2' => string 'v2'
    'k3' => string 'v3'
```

I really need your help, thank you in advance.

Comment: your all three array have same length means same number of element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about...

```
$resultArr = array();

foreach($whatever as $thing) {

  $k1 = GetKey1(); 
  $v1 = GetValue1();

  $k2 = GetKey2();
  $v2 = GetValue2();

  $k3 = GetKey3();
  $v2 = GetValue3();

  //  now I put those keys and values in associative array called DataArr
  $DataArr = array();  
  $DataArr[$k1] = $v1;
  $DataArr[$k2] = $v2;
  $DataArr[$k3] = $v3;

  $resultArr[] = $DataArr;

}
```

Comment: wow man, that worked like magic, I really cant thank you enough, you saved me so much trouble :)

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

```
int array_push ( array &$array , mixed $value1 [, mixed $... ] )
```

or

```
<?php
/**
* @desc array_push and removes elements from the beginning of the array until it is within limit
* @param    array   Array to push on to
* @param    mixed   Passed to array push as 2nd parameter
* @param    int     Limit (default = 10)
* 
* @return   array   New array
*/
function array_push_limit($array,$add,$limit=10){
    array_push($array, $add);    
    do {        
        array_shift($array);
        $size=count($array);        
    } while($size > $limit);

    return $array;
}
?>
----------
EXAMPLE:
----------
<?php
    $array=array(1, -5, 23, -66, 33, 54, 3);    
    print_r(array_push_limit($array, "HELLO", 4));
?>
----------
OUTPUT:
----------
Array
(
    [0] => 33
    [1] => 54
    [2] => 3
    [3] => HELLO
)
```